# kotlin KMM face for watchOS?

Tags: kotlin, watchos, kmm, watchface

Is it possible to create a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) watch face?

It is possible to set a watchOS target for a KMM app, but this seems to be primarily for a regular watchOS app. I cannot find any documentation about doing this for a watch face.

Any thoughts on if / how this could be  done?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a watchOS target in your build.gradle.kts.

```
iosTarget("ios") {
        ...
    }
watchos()
```

Please take a look at official documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-share-on-platforms.html#use-target-shortcuts